# GeoFence using PendingIntent.getBroadcast() not working

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-8.0-oreo, android-geofence, android-8.1-oreo

I am trying get a `Geofence` trigger to a `BroadcastReceiver` and the `BroadcastReceiver` has the code to read the data from the intent and act on the data sent in intent. My `BroadCastReceiver` is `GeoLocationBroadCastReceiver`. I am invoking this code when my activity is opened and the app is in background.

```
public PendingIntent getPendingIntent(Context context){
   Intent i = new Intent(context, GeoLocationBroadCastReceiver.class);
   return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```

This `PendingIntent` is passed to the addGeofences method along with the `GeofencingRequest.Builder`(this data is returned in the addGeoFence method).

```
GeofencingClient client = LocationServices.getGeofencingClient(context);
 client.addGeofences(addGeoFence(100, lat, long, true), getPendingIntent(context))
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        Log.e(TAG,"Added from location geofence");
                    }
                });
```

When I invoke the above code the geofence is added successfully.

Receiver declaration in Manifest.xml file:

```
 <receiver
        android:name=".LocationMagic.GeoLocationBroadCastReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"/>
```

The problem: I am not getting broadcast and the receiver is not called. I see the google suggested approach is to use the broadcast to overcome the background limitations with services. I know the Broadcast limitations as well(whitelisted and blacklisted). But as per google codelabs the suggested approach is to use broadcast. Google code labs link [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/background-location-updates-android-o/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#6).

From google codelabs:

> Apps targeting O are further subject to limits on services started in
>   the background. For this reason, apps targeting O should not use
>   PendingIntent.getService() when requesting location updates. Instead,
>   they should use PendingIntent.getBroadcast().

Comment: Did you solve this issue

Comment: No..could not reslove it

Comment: @RuchirBaronia Were u able to resolve it

Comment: No I could not :(